# How to get the IP address used by a Parallels VM from the host?

Tags: parallels

Parallels has a command line API which is documented [here](http://www.parallels.com/fileadmin/parallels/documents/support/pdfm/Parallels_Command_Line_Reference_Guide.pdf)

```
>prlctl list
UUID                                    STATUS       IP_ADDR         NAME
{ca50aac6-caa6-47a6-9bfe-e38f6261cb8d}  running      -               win7
```

Still, even with this the IP_ADDR reported is always empty, even if the machine is running as has an internet connection.

How can I find the IP of the machine from the guest? I need a way to connect to the guest, by using a domain name or an IP.

Comment: Unfortunately `prlctl` is now a Pro-only feature...

Comment: @LarsBilke which means more reasons to scrap Parallels for VirtualBox, even if is clearly not so cool but is clearly more than OK for 9/10 users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it's a Windows VM, you can get the IP with the following command from the host:

```
prlctl exec "VM Name" ipconfig | grep "IPv4" | grep -o '\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}'
```

For a *nix VM:

```
prlctl exec "VM Name" ifconfig eth1 | grep "inet " | grep -o 'addr:\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}' | grep -o '\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}'
```

Comment: This answer should start with "If Parallels Tools are installed on the guest..."  "exec" command only works with guest with the Tools installed.

Comment: wow, with this I don't even need to know the ip address to ssh to the VM remotely, as I can just run the commands directly - which is a good thing if ssh/telnet connections are being rejected.

Comment: Great. Now to figure out why it's got a default address which suggests it didn't DHCP properly...

Comment: This is the message I get when I run your script: "The command is available only in Parallels Desktop for Mac Pro or Business Edition."

Answer (score 15):

I stumbled upon this today and found it questionable that the `list` command shows an `IP_ADDR` but never the IP. I checked the most recent docs for the `prlctl` command and its states:

> -f, --full
>
> Shows the real IP address(es) for running virtual machines.

Providing this flag displays the IP addresses for me

`prlctl list -f`

Answer (score 12):

if you want to access the machine using SSH there is a built in command that can help with this.

`prlctl enter <VM_ID|VM_NAME>`

This will open a prompt as root to the VM
if you want the IP for any other reason there is another way to get it

`prlctl exec <VM_ID|VM_NAME> ifconfig`

The `exec` command from `prlctl` will execute the `ifconfig` command on the host linux machine (if using windows do `ipconfig` instead of `ifconfig`)

All the output of the `ifconfig` will be printed on your terminal and the ip will be clearly visible in the output

Comment: Using "enter" for SSH is definitely the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking for this exact feature for days now. Thank you!

Comment: This answer should start with "If Parallels Tools are installed on the guest..." Both "enter" and "exec" command only works with guest with the Tools installed.

Comment: Also, "prlctl enter" is not SSH.   It seems to be connecting to the console directly, even bypassing the authentication via parallels own protocol.

Comment: Putting an example here: `prlctl exec 'Windows 10' ipconfig | grep IP` where "Windows 10" is the name of my windows VM as shown in `prlctl list`.